# Transform 2 columns at once using Html.Table in powerquery-m

Tags: html, powerbi, powerquery, m

This is my data:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WSo0pNTAwMlO2NDWzVshNLcnIT1HSUYIJmphZ6xaXFJUml5QWpSrF6kQrJefnFZck5pUowJSYGVgja7CwNjR2BhqUWAzUkZuaV6IUGwsA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [col1 = _t, col2 = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"col1", type text}, {"col2", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

[image: Power BI - HTML decimal values in 2 columns]

I know how to add a column with decoded text using `Html.Table` (2 lines are added):

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WSo0pNTAwMlO2NDWzVshNLcnIT1HSUYIJmphZ6xaXFJUml5QWpSrF6kQrJefnFZck5pUowJSYGVgja7CwNjR2BhqUWAzUkZuaV6IUGwsA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [col1 = _t, col2 = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"col1", type text}, {"col2", type text}}),
    HtmlTable = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "HtmlTable", each Html.Table([col1],{{"HtmlDecoded",":root"}})),
    #"Expanded HtmlTable" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(HtmlTable, "HtmlTable", {"HtmlDecoded"}, {"HtmlDecoded"})
in
    #"Expanded HtmlTable"
```

[image: Power BI - Added decoded HTML table using Html.Table]

But can I do it with both columns at the same time? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transforming both columns, even without adding new ones:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WSo0pNTAwMlO2NDWzVshNLcnIT1HSUYIJmphZ6xaXFJUml5QWpSrF6kQrJefnFZck5pUowJSYGVgja7CwNjR2BhqUWAzUkZuaV6IUGwsA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [col1 = _t, col2 = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"col1", type text}, {"col2", type text}}),
    Decoded = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", {
        {"col1", each Table.FirstValue(Html.Table(_,{{"t1",":root"}}))}, 
        {"col2", each Table.FirstValue(Html.Table(_,{{"t2",":root"}}))} } )
in
    Decoded
```